# Tabs are not the whole screen

Tags: java, android

I use the layout of Android Studio (drawer and tabs), the tabs are in a fragment.

As you can see in the screenshot below, they are not under the toolbar, and displayed in the middle. What could be the problem?

[image]

**tab-main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orange"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: Post your layout xml

Comment: autogenerated layout from activity/fragment creation now has paddings = 16dp, just remove them

Comment: You included this tab main xml somewhere. Show that too

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And what to delete?

Comment: put padding in tab layout

Comment: Eeeeee! Thank you! deleted in the content_view paddings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tabs might not take the full width because of margin/padding on the container in which you've added the `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`.

The tab bar can also be part of the top toolbar. Then the tabs will match the toolbar styling, for this you can use the `AppBarLayout`: [see support lib JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html). In this layout you include both a `Toolbar` and the `TabLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your TabLayout:

> app:tabMode="fixed"

It will tell the layout to stretch the tabs to fit the width of the screen
Also notice that if the view have margin (from the view or parent views) it will not work